# How can I close a child window?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to provide a button on my child page that would close the child page from the child page itself. To make matters worse, I didn't write the child page - it is written using frames. So far I've tried this code in the child page:

```
Window.opener.location= '/parent page.html';
Window.close();
```

And, in the body:

```
<a href="JavaScript:if(confirm('close window?')) window.close()">close</a>
```

HELP!

Comment: If it helps, the child page was created by google picasa.  I'm able to get the word "close" to appear on the page, and the pop up window appears to confirm if I want to close the window, but nothing happens when I click "yes"

Comment: You can close only those pages that were opened via Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the link you inserted is inside an iframe, use `window.top.close()` instead of `window.close()`. `window.top` will refer to child window you created.

HTML for your hyperlink will be

```
<a href="javascript: if(confirm('close window')) {window.top.opener.location ='/auctioneer notes 8_22_12.html';window.top.close();}">close window</a>
```

Comment: Your answer was cut off (I think)

Comment: Duh, forgive me I'm new to this. I tried all of your code, but it still is not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you tell how me child window was created? If you are using hyperlink to create one then on parent page edit the link as `<a href="Javascript: window.open('url of the page')">Click this Link</a>`

Comment: I am using a form and a button to open the child window from the parent window:

Comment: I'm sorry psjinx - I keep trying to use my ipad to answer when I should be cutting and pasting from my computer. Here's how the code looks in the parent window: <input type="button" value="2005 Enclosed Trailer" onClick="open_win()" /> and this is what is under script: <script type="text/javascript"> function open_win() { window.open('/photogallery/08_22_12/2005 Enclosed Trailer/index.html'); } </script>   It opens the child window perfectly!

Comment: Can you give some public url to this so that I can debug?

Comment: Http://www.sharplessauctions.com/auctioneer notes 08_22_12.html is parent. Child is:  http://www.sharplessauctions.com/photogallery/08_22_12/2005 Enclosed Trailer/target0.html

Answer (score 0):

This is cheating, but by refreshing the parent window the child window gets closed. Not very elegant but it works.

```
<form METHOD=post><p align=right><input TYPE="button" VALUE="Close This Window"onClick="window.parent.location.reload();"></p></form>
```